# kotlin - Type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList<TypeA> but MutableList<InterfaceType> was expected

Tags: kotlin, inferred-type

I'm trying to code some stuff in kotlin but I have some problem with that. How can i achieve this problem?  I share my code.. Please help me!

```
interface InterfaceType {}

open class ConcreteImpl: InterfaceType {}

class TypeA: ConcreteImpl() {}

fun test() {

    var interfaceTypeList: MutableList<InterfaceType> = mutableListOf()

    var typeAList: MutableList<TypeA> = mutableListOf()

    interfaceTypeList = typeAList

}
```

[You can show the code from here.](https://pl.kotl.in/MxlEaG3vr)

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to Kotlin types [`variance`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance).

The type `MutableList<T>` is **invariant** in its type `T` so you can't assign a `MutableList<InterfaceType>` to a `MutableList<TypeA>`.

To be able to assign it, since `InterfaceType` is a supertype of `TypeA`, you'd need instead a class **covariant** in its type (e.g. `List`).

```kotlin
interface InterfaceType {}

open class ConcreteImpl: InterfaceType {}

class TypeA: ConcreteImpl() {}

fun test() {
    var interfaceTypeList: List<InterfaceType> = mutableListOf()
    var typeAList: MutableList<TypeA> = mutableListOf()
    interfaceTypeList = typeAList
}
```

Otherwise you should make an unchecked cast to `MutableList<InterfaceType>`.

````kotlin
```kotlin
interface InterfaceType {}

open class ConcreteImpl: InterfaceType {}

class TypeA: ConcreteImpl() {}

fun test() {
    var interfaceTypeList: MutableList<InterfaceType> = mutableListOf()
    var typeAList: MutableList<TypeA> = mutableListOf()
    // Unchecked cast.
    interfaceTypeList = typeAList as MutableList<InterfaceType>
}
````